# JQuery add onclick for links with same class

Tags: jquery, onclick

The site has links with the ".tel" class

```
<a class='tel' href="http://example.com">Link</a>
```

For all these links, how to add

```
onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('http://example.com/');"
```

I want to get a link like this

```
<a class='tel' onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('http://example.com');" href="http://example.com">Link</a>
```

Comment: Any introductory jQuery tutorial or documentation will include examples of how to attach a click handler to an element or set of elements.  (And it's definitely *not* what you're illustrating here.)  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: Also depends on what "gtag_report_conversion" does - if it's any sort of ajax then you'll want to suspend / cancel the link.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right, I think you're looking for the solution to add custom attribute to HTML elements. If this is the case you can do in the following way

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href].tel').attr('onclick', "return gtag_report_conversion('http://example.com/');");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a class='tel' href="http://example.com">Link - 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class='tel' href="http://example.com">Link - 2</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class='tel' href="http://example.com">Link - 3</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class='tel' href="http://example.com">Link - 4</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class='tel' href="http://example.com">Link - 5</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a class='telephone' href="http://example.com">Link - 6</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a class='telephone' href="http://example.com">Link - 7</a>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```